# Why ajax redirected to action url after aborting other ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to cancel other executed ajax calls on form submission, because others ajax taking too much time to complete

I aborting other ajax calls and then creating new ajax request as like below

```
function createPaypalPayment(paypal_form_data,route){
    if (ajax_one !== null) {
        ajax_one.abort();
    }
    if (ajax_two !== null) {
        ajax_two.abort();
    }
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: route,
        data: paypal_form_data.serialize(), 
        success: function(response)
        {
            ....
        }

    });
}
```

But when I abort other ajax request then this ajax request redirect to provided action url, however that url is return json response accordingly.

Can someone kindly guide me why it is happening I would like to appreciate.

Comment: show your other ajax calls

Comment: tell us what version of jQuery you're using

Comment: @Kaushik other ajaxs call are same as this one

Comment: @vladawtsu it is `jQuery v3.2.1`

Comment: ajax call should not redirect. Can you give us more code

Comment: @vladawtsu trust me there is no other code

Comment: please provide your complete code along with previous ajax call otherwise its difficult to identify

Comment: @ImranAbbas please mention how you call this function, from where you call this function.

Comment: @HareshVidja Yes sure, in document ready event, I am calling this function on-submit event

Comment: @ImranAbbas, can you add that code on your question description?